# Fortran extend assignment interface

Tags: fortran

Is it possible to extend a copy assignment to an extended type? It would make a program easier to maintain if the parent class needs to be changed.

I want to call the parent class copy assignment in the extended type's coy assignment. When I do this I run into an issue. If I want the extended type to access the parent types copy assignment, then I need to use `class` instead of `type` in the parent copy assignment subroutine. However, if the parent copy assignment uses class instead of type, then it is indistinguishable from the extended type's copy assignment (compiler error: Ambiguous interfaces in intrinsic assignment operator).

If I leave the parent's copy assignment as `type` instead of `class` then the issue is a "type mismatch" if I try to call the parent copy assignment in the extended copy assignment.

I tried to create the simplest example of this below.

Is there any way to call a parent's copy assignment from an extended type.

```
module types

implicit none

type, public :: square
    real(8) :: length
end type

type, extends(square), public :: squareColor
    integer :: r, g, b
end type 

interface assignment(=)
    module procedure :: copySquare
    module procedure :: copySquareColor
    ! module procedure :: copySquareColorDesired
end interface

contains

subroutine copySquare( copyTo, copyFrom )
    class(square), intent(out) :: copyTo
    class(square), intent(in)  :: copyFrom
    
    copyTo%length = copyFrom%length

end subroutine copySquare

subroutine copySquareColor( copyTo, copyFrom )
    type(squareColor), intent(out) :: copyTo
    type(squareColor), intent(in)  :: copyFrom
    
    copyTo%length = copyFrom%length

    copyTo%r      = copyFrom%r
    copyTo%g      = copyFrom%g
    copyTo%b      = copyFrom%b

end subroutine copySquareColor

! Can't compile with this assignment subroutine 
! becuase call copySquare will cause a type mismatch error
! subroutine copySquareColorDesired( copyTo, copyFrom )
!     type(squareColor), intent(out) :: copyTo
!     type(squareColor), intent(in)  :: copyFrom
    
!     call copySquare( copyTo, copyFrom )
!     copyTo%r      = copyFrom%r
!     copyTo%g      = copyFrom%g
!     copyTo%b      = copyFrom%b

! end subroutine copySquareColorDesired

end module types

program extendAssignment

use types
implicit none

type(squareColor) :: squareColor1, squareColor2

squareColor1%length = 5
squareColor1%r = 120
squareColor1%g = 200
squareColor1%b = 250

squareColor2 = squareColor1

print *, squareColor2%length, squareColor2%r, squareColor2%g, squareColor2%b


end program
```

Comment: Do you know that `type(squareColor) x` means `x%square` exists and is of `type(square)`?

Comment: If you can't get the idea from that and the linked question, please [edit] to show your effort and we can reopen/address.